# Pass custom attributes to presignup trigger lambda amplify google login

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm implementing google sign in using aws amplify and cognito in my react application.I want to store users data in database.so i want to pass some data from front-end to while google sign in.So i can use it in pre sign up trigger and store users information in database.But in docs i didn't find any method to do that.Amplify provides

`Auth.federatedSignIn({provider:'Google'})`

Method for google sign in
we can pass custom state as `{provider:'Google', customState:'state'}`
But custom state in not appearing in preSignUp lambda trigger event.

Comment: did u found a solution to this ??